# "Remote computer is not available." is the error thrown when reading from remote public windows server 2003 queue

Tags: queue, msmq, windows-server-2003

I keep getting the error “Remote computer is not available.” when reading from remote public windows server 2003 queue. The queue is on server B. My application is on server A;

- Amazingly, server A can drop a message on any queue on server B, i just can't read a message off from B.
- The two servers A and B are on the same domain.
- all other servers can read and write on B's queues
- it happened after I restarted server A
- i have restarted A again in vain
- msmq is running on A and B
  Online suggestions are all not working.

It doesn't look like a trust issue between servers A and B. Please help

Comment: The dude [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2008/07/10/getting-msmq-messages-out-of-windows-server-2008.aspx) says i have to open ports 135 and 2103/2105 with reference to info [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2008/04/29/clear-the-way-msmq-coming-through.aspx). I have requested the IT-Systems guys to open 135 which i couldn't telnet. Will post if this succeeds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. The approach in my comment above worked.
The thing is, port 135 was blocked by our IT-Networks guys. This doesn't immediately affect pulling messages. It had to be after restarting server A that B rejected its request due to failed RPC requests.
Again, thanks to [MSMQ from the plumber's mate](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2008/07/10/getting-msmq-messages-out-of-windows-server-2008.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage)